# Laravel query builder setting id to 0 not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm seeding the categories table, when I run:

```
    DB::table('cats')->insert([
        'id' => 0,
        'parent_cat_id' => null,
        'name' => 'Uncategorized'
    ]);
```

But the inserted row's id will be 1, if I try to update the id manually on db It's possible.

Anything other than zero works in query builder (e.g. `'id'=>5`)

**Edit**:
 Currently this hack is working, what's the problem with `insert()` if `update()` can change the id to `0`?

```
    DB::table('cats')->insert([
        'id' => 100,
        'parent_cat_id' => null,
        'name' => 'Uncategorized'
    ]);
    DB::table('cats')->where('id',100)->update(['id' => 0]);
```

My migration schema:

```
    Schema::create('cats', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedInteger('parent_cat_id')->nullable();
    });
```

Comment: may be your cats table id is defined as unsigned

Comment: As @RAUSHANKUMAR said please check your schema for type of id field.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR but I can update that to zero

Comment: This isn't an issue with Laravel but rather MySQL. Even if you try something like: `ALTER TABLE cats AUTO_INCREMENT = 0` it will actually change it to 1. Your workaround is probably going to be the easiest way to go about it (or settle with `Uncategorized` have an id of 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you defined `id` column with:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

That's `UNSIGNED INTEGER` equivalent.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations

**Update**

To create auto incrementing not unsigned field, do this:

```
$table->integer('id');
$table->primary('id');
```

> Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an int automatically.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: Yes that's true, I wanted an increment id. but I want to be able to insert a 0 id, and I can do that directly in db, but why is it impossible in eloquent->insert?

Comment: Change it to `$table->integer('id'); $table->primary('id');` and recreate the table.

Comment: Unsigned integers can be 0

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin but I need id to be increments... you mean I need to handle `id++` manually?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin thanks for the update, I made this change but it didn't make it auto_increment.

Comment: @Webinan I can't try it now, but according to Laravel docs, it should be auto incrementing. Are you sure table was recreated? Also, try to add `public $incrementing = true;` to the model.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes, the table is updated, ok, I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: I would imagine the down-vote is because you've said unsigned integers can't be 0 when they can be https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html.

Answer (score 4):

I solved with this:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('cats', function (Blueprint $table) {
       DB::statement('SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";');
       //run other migrations 
   }
}
```

The sql_mode MySQL variable tells MySQL if it should interpret 0 INSERTs as a true 0, not a PRIMARY KEY generation request.

Comment: I wrote the `DB:statement....` sentence on seeder self

Answer (score 0):

change your migration file. then use command - php artisan migrate

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->index();
        $table->string('token')->index();
        $table->timestamp('created_at');
    });
```

Comment: I've pasted my migration in the question. What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

Put `DB::statement("SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';");` in Seeder run method then `Model::create(['id' => 0...]);` rest you can ignore id;
In `Schema` you can just give `$table->id() || $table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->primary() or $table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->autoIncrement();`